# MySQL Geometry Type for 3 coordinate values

Tags: mysql, geospatial, autocad, mysql-8.0

I am seeking information on how to create a MySQL Geometry type that accepts 3 coordinate values: Northing, Easting, and Elevation.

I can create a `POINT` data type (with SRID) and populate it with:

`ST_SRID(POINT(Northing, Easting), SRID_value_Here)`

but a POINT only accepts 2 arguments (based on my understanding).

The Elevation value I need to store is significant as these points will be linked to an AutoCad drawing and stored in a MySQL database.

I guess I am unclear on what Geospatial data type to use as I don't necessarily feel this is a Polygon since it is just a single point entity with 3 coordinate values and not 3 separate points that could close in an form a polygon.

While I am familiar with SQL, Geospatial is a new and opening world to me so any help and pointers are much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: for what i know  ..  there is not the altitude (z)  in mysql., only x, y ..  the spatial db that use 3 dimension  is postgis / postgresql